# UIKit or CoreGraphics memory leak

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks

It looks like I am experiencing memory leaks in Cocoa libraries? Is it possible? What are your experiences? How can I eventually fix them?

[leaks http://www.objectivec.cz/transfer/memoryleaks.png](http://www.objectivec.cz/transfer/memoryleaks.png)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Cocoa libraries were developed by people, so they can make some mistakes. If you sure, that you have founded leak in standard SDK then inform Apple http://developer.apple.com/support/.

Comment: Vince> I don't understand. By this report lib is clearly forgetting release memory.

Comment: @Engeor - I must agree with beryllium, code is written by someone, so, yes a bug is still possible. However, looking for a bug in standard SDK is the very last option to consider. It is likely that the leak lies in your code. Moreover, I can't see *by this report* the framework responsible for the leak.