# Memory Leak in UIKit (not my code) in iOS app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit

I'm trying to solve a memory leak in my iOS app and struggling. I'm using the leaks tool to try to isolate the problem. To my surprise, the leak seems to be happening 100% within the UITableView gesture recognizer code. Specifically, the leak count increments each time I stop scrolling (release) the UITableView. Even weirder, this happens with a UIWebView as well. And with a UIScrollView.

So each time I release a drag action on any of these UIKit objects, I get a memory leak. The UI pieces are at different, distinct places around my app, so it's not just localized to one screen.

Ideas?

[image]

Comment: This is a UIKit bug that has been reported. See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762995/memory-leak-every-time-uiscrollview-is-released

Comment: Thanks Rickay. Also found this answser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822998/uikit-or-coregraphics-memory-leak

Comment: @Zane: [You should file](http://bugreport.apple.com) your own copy of the bug; although they're probably working on it anyways, Apple is known to take the squeakiness of the wheel into account when deciding what to grease first.

Comment: Thanks... I'm currently working for a better workaround, too. Subclassing a UITableView, for example, destroys the table's ability to scroll... ugh.