# iOS system libraries leaks normal?

Tags: ios, ios8.3

![enter image description here][1]Seems like all from system libs, none from my app.

I am using AFNetworking and PonyDebugger with ARC by the way.

1. Are these leaks normal?
2. Does the tool give false positives?

Comment: What exactly is this picture showing? Allocations? I don't think this picture shows leaks.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had a similar question, here's a quote from Apple's Instruments Guide

> An instrument such as the Leaks instrument can also point out places where your app is not handling memory properly. If the graph for Leaks is relatively empty, you know that your app is behaving properly

Well, AppKit, UIKit and other are developed by people, so there can be bugs! As far as I know they even track them. So, generally, if you don't see objects which you create in code, and you are sure they are not yours 100%, then this is iOS business and if it is `relatively` empty, that is OK.

Though it is difficult to tell about AFNetworking as it is an external library.

Comment: Yeah, I even wrote very simple UI-only app, just to play with the Leaks instruments, and sometimes there were leaks. But it is obvious that code "I wrote" has no leaks in it.

Comment: Here's a similar discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497166/memory-leak-in-uikit-not-my-code-in-ios-app

Comment: Just to be sure(check) that your code is not involved